# Use trained neural network with images showing broader surrounding context

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

Model has been trained, it reliably recognises dogs from cats in tiny pictures like the following:

[image]

All these pictures are pretty much always centered on the cat/dog, and the cat/dog occupies almost all the image frame. There is little to none additional surrounding context, which allows the network to train very efficiently.

The next step is, how to make sure that the same model will effectively tell that in the picture below, there happens to be a cat, similar to the ones used to train the model, but surrounded by a broader environment?

[image]

Are there some specific steps to take when the model is supposed to be used in production with images showing a broader context than in training? Or is the model able to detect it automagically?

Answer (score 1):

It decreasing order of effectiveness, the steps you can take are:

1. Use more training data, with images having larger borders.
2. Augment existing training images with borders, maybe through random or mirrored padding.
3. Try cropping out the borders during inference, creating multiple images with different borders. Pick the run with the best result.

Comment: Would using a selection algorithm (the kind that draws bounding boxes around cats) help? I'm referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402760/object-detection-with-r-cnn/43406468#43406468

Comment: RCNN, YOLO etc. are state-of-the-art architectures. These networks are overkill for your application. It's like using a 8-core processor on a phone that only makes calls - it can get the job done, but you end up wasting resources.

Comment: I see. My example however was a toy example to avoid getting into too many details. A closer illustration of what I'm trying to do is to classify between cats having a striped pattern and cats having a plain furr. If I train the network on plain/striped cats shown in context, the network doesn't pick any difference. It does if I crop the picture on the cat, but then I'm wondering how to get to best recall when the actual, production-like pictures feature a broad environment with one cat somewhere. Hence my suggestion of using a box-detection first, to help center on the cat. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, in that case using networks for localization would work.